how to remove an attribute of an element using mutationObserver and mutationrecord?
I've been using this code below to remove attributes added by a 3rd party library from my webapp on runtime.
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', () => {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-owns]');
  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.removeAttribute('aria-owns')
  })
})

However recently, we've been getting this error in the console:

[Deprecation] Listener added for a 'DOMNodeInserted' mutation event.
Support for this event type has been removed, and this event will no
longer be fired. See https://chromestatus.com/feature/5083947249172480
for more information.

The summary is that DOMNodeInserted shouldn't be used anymore for performance reasons, and more importantly bc it will stop working in the near future. It links to an article that mentions that using MutationObserver is the viable option.
However, MutationObserver doesn't expose Elements, just nodes.
This is what I tried:
const observer= new MutationObserver(mutationList =>{
  mutationList.forEach(mutationRecord => {
    const elements= document.querySelectorAll('[aria-owns]');
    elements.forEach(element => 
      element.removeAttribute('aria-owns')
    )
  })
});
observer.observe(document, {
  childList: true, 
  subtree: true, 
  attributeFilter: ['aria-owns']
};

but if I understand correctly how MutationObserver works, then it feels like an overkill to get all the elements in the document with document.querySelectorAll('[aria-owns]') then iterate over them one by one to remove the attribute, if mutationRecod already yields a collection of the nodes that have just mutated and contain the attribute I am looking for.
is there a way to access the element from the nodes yielded by the MutationObserver?
or what is the correct way to edit the attributes of the nodes with a MutationObserver?

Posting my own answer as I've found this works, however I am not sure this is the right way to do this, but it somehow looks better than what I was trying before (I am working on typescript):
const observer= new MutationObserver(mutationList =>
  mutationList.forEach(mutationRecord=> 
    (mutationRecord.target as Element).removeAttribute('aria-owns')
  )
);
observer.observe(document, {
  childList: true, 
  subtree: true, 
  attributeFilter: ['aria-owns']
};


In the case that a MutationRecord's type is "childList", the newly-added nodes of interest will be on the property addedNodes instead of target (which will be the parent of those nodes). I posted an answer to demonstrate this.

TypeScript offers a feature called a type guard function that uses a runtime check to narrow an existing type to a subtype. You can use this feature to discriminate whether or not a Node is an Element:

Ref: Node: nodeType property

TS Playground
function isElement(node: Node): node is Element {
  return node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE;
}

declare const node: Node;

if (isElement(node)) {
  node
  //^? const node: Element
} else {
  node
  //^? const node: Node
}

You can use that type guard to inform the compiler while writing the code that runs in the MutationObserver callback. Here's a functional example:
TS Playground
function observeAndRemove(): MutationObserver {
  const attributeName = "aria-owns";

  function isElement(node: Node): node is Element {
    return node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE;
  }

  function removeAttr(node: Node): void {
    if (isElement(node) && node.hasAttribute(attributeName)) {
      node.removeAttribute(attributeName);
    }
  }

  function handleMutationRecord(mutationRecord: MutationRecord): void {
    switch (mutationRecord.type) {
      case "attributes": {
        if (mutationRecord.attributeName === attributeName) {
          removeAttr(mutationRecord.target);
        }
        break;
      }
      case "childList": {
        for (const node of mutationRecord.addedNodes) {
          removeAttr(node);
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationRecords) => {
    for (const mutationRecord of mutationRecords) {
      handleMutationRecord(mutationRecord);
    }
  });

  observer.observe(document, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributeFilter: [attributeName],
  });

  return observer;
}

const observer = observeAndRemove();
// Maybe later…
// if (condition) observer.disconnect();

